# Page body does not extend to bottom of display when zooming out

Tags: html, css

I'm experiencing a small issue with my website. When a user zooms out of the page, the body (white part) won't extend to the bottom of the display. Here's what I mean

[image: example]

There's no issue when the user is at a normal zoom, but after around 50% zoom, the problem starts to occur. How can I fix this?

[image: inspect element]

Comment: maybe making it fixed?

Comment: Hey. can you add some code so we can try fix your code and go about it that way? :) What I would recommend is setting the height of the element to min-width: 100vh;

Comment: @RyanEarnshaw Thanks for the reply! Your suggestion actually worked, but I think you meant min-height not min-width. Nonetheless, I added min-height: 100vh; to the page-inner element and it works like a charm! Thanks :)

Comment: Hey! yes sorry I got mixed up haha no worries I will add this as an answer if you can mark it that would be wonderful :)

Comment: @RyanEarnshaw Sure, just gotta wait a couple of minutes before I'm able to accept it as the solution. Anyway, there's a slight issue. min-height: 100vh; seems to bug the scrollbar on firefox for some reason, but you can still scroll fine with the mouse scroll wheel, but not actually with the vertical scroll bar. Seems to work fine on Chrome, though.

Comment: Thanks bud! :) how does it bug the scrollbar in firefox? as in you cant click on it anymore?

Comment: @RyanEarnshaw You can click on it but it won't move. (firefox - http://prntscr.com/gykqrk) but on google chrome - http://prntscr.com/gykr0j (scrollbar functions properly)

Comment: you could user `overflow:hidden;` My guess is that its not working because there is no content above or below to even scroll to in the first place and its getting confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting:

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

Documentation is available [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_minheight.asp) but its pretty self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height: 100vh`

CSS3 gives us viewport-relative units. 100vw means 100% of the viewport width. 100vh; 100% of the height.